# How do I properly aggregate mongodb results from two separate content types in my node.js app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How do I properly aggregate results in a view using node.js & mongoose from mongodb. My programmer colleague came up with the following route to aggregate event and blog posts in one list/view of content sorted by day (if both "published" and "promoted" equal 1). The trouble with this is that the list of aggregate results is really just split into two (first events display, then blogs display) when they should render in a truly mixed fashion sorted by date. I would use a join or groupby in mysql but how would I do this type of aggregation in a node.js app with mongodb? Ps, we're using express and mongoose in case that helps.

Update: We've already defined the schema for the two (events and blogs), and there are thousands of records already stored. So the question now is, can we do this client side or do we have to create an index (another collection)? I'm reading up on mongodb's aggregation framework and map reduce as well but I'm not sure if either of those can help me at this point.

```
    app.get('/promoted/content/:page?', userSession, function(req, res, next) {
var today = todayTimestamp();

var limit = 10;
if(req.params.page) {
    var skip = req.params.page * limit;
} else {
    var skip = 0;
}

async.parallel({
    blogs: function(callback){
        app.Blog.find()
            .where('status').equals(1)
            .where('promote').equals(1)
            .sort('sticky', -1)
            .sort('created', -1)
            .populate('userId')
            .exec(function(err, blogs) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    callback(null, blogs);
                }
        });
    },
    events: function(callback){
        app.Event.find()
            .where('status').equals(1)
            .where('promote').equals(1)
            .sort('sticky', -1)
            .sort('created', -1)
            .populate('userId')
            .exec(function(err, events) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    callback(null, events);
                }
        });
    }
},
// callback function to render page and pass in all data
function(err, results){

    //add type field to results for logic in mixed output
    for(i = 0; i < results.blogs.length; i++) {
        results.blogs[i].type = 'blog';
    }
    for(i = 0; i < results.events.length; i++) {
        results.events[i].type = 'event';
    }

    //combine results from blogs and events and sort the results
    var promoted = results.events.concat(results.blogs);
    var outputted = false;
    promoted.sort(function( a, b )
    {
      // Sort by key of modification date in each array
      if ( a['changed'] == b['changed'] ) return 0;
      return a['changed'] < b['changed'] ? -1 : -1;
    });

    //create a subset
    var subset = new Array();
    for(var i = skip; i < (limit + skip); i++) {
        subset.push(promoted[i]);
    }

    //check mobile
    if(isMobile(req)) {
        res.render('mobile/fragments/block_posts', { posts: subset, user: req.session.user, message: req.flash()});
    } else {
        res.render('fragments/block_posts', { posts: subset, user: req.session.user, message: req.flash()});
    }
});
```

Comment: One thing, you should probably callback with the error from the asyc.parallel, otherwise you'll leave the client hanging.  ie. `if (err) { console.log(err);}  callback(err, events);`

Comment: Would I write that as follows: if (err) {
      console.log(err);
     } else {
      callback(err, events);
     }

Comment: Without the `else`, as you want the callback to happen whether there is an error or not, so that errors can be handled in the final function.

Comment: There are no joins in mongodb.  You query 1 collection at a time.  But what you might want to do is reconsider your schema design.  If `Blog` and `Event` are so similar as to be queried at the same time, on the same attributes, perhaps they should just be documents in the same collection distingushed by type?  This would solve your problem while still allowing them to be queried separately.  If the two models have a lot of differing business logic (methods, hooks, etc), you might look into implementing some kind of inheritance, e.g. https://github.com/briankircho/mongoose-schema-extend

Comment: Unfortunately, we're too far along the project to change the schema (several thousand records made already) and the two are different in many regards (they have many distinct fields). This schema-extend is pretty interesting but it looks like we're too late to take advantage of that as well. I have been reading up on mongodb 2.2's aggregation framework; could that help us achieve what we're looking for?

Comment: Nope, the aggregation framework, and traditional map-reduce, still operate on one collection at a time.  Even though the project has live records I still might advocate the 1-collection approach with a data migration for the existing docs.  The different doc types do not need to share the all the same fields, and could even be indexed separately.  Barring that, you could possibly keep a 3rd collection of "PublishedDocs" which refer to docs in the other 2 collections, but if I was going to have to migrate data anyway, I'd probably just go with the 1-collection option.

Comment: Thanks for ideas. I'll update the thread when we decide on a solution. It looks like we're going to have to change the schema if we want to solve this issue. Just one last question here: so would you use aggregation framework or map reduce at all or just create another singular collection and query from that?

Comment: For this I'd just query the one collection normally.  Aggregation would become useful if you needed to do grouping, calculations, manipulate subdocs, etc.  Typically you'll want to prefer aggregation over map-reduce for queries (aggregation was introduced as a way to do map-reduce tasks more quickly).